# PHP + Mysql: how to extract similar result sorted by similarity

Tags: php, mysql, similarity

I need to get records from a large database and sort by similarity with a certain string.
For example, in searching results for the word "Pasta":

- the use of Levenshtein distance produces acceptable results, but it is slow (and at the moment the provider does not give me permissions to create functions)

[image]

- the use of FULLTEXT gives me unacceptable values

[image]

- much less the LIKE and SOUNDEX commands

I was evaluating various tools, (Soir, Elasticsearch, ...).

Are they useful for my purpose?

Which one can I address considering that:

- must be opern-source
- I don't have the ability to install daemon or anything else on the server